# Could an artificial ring system around the earth produce a net-positive effect on climate change?

Tags: earth, climate-science

The greenhouse effect as I understand it is because sunlight hits the Earth, and is re-radiated as infrared heat, which is then trapped by greenhouse gasses in the atmosphere, like CO2 and Methane.

So would a ring system of low-albedo material (say, coal dust) intercept some percentage of that sunlight, re-radiate it in infrared, trapping it on the wrong side of the greenhouse gasses to contribute to warming? Or is this a misunderstanding of how greenhouse gasses in the atmosphere work?  Are there any potential secondary effects that would negate the benefit?

Additional side question... would the optimal ring position be -23.4° off the plane of the ecliptic so that it's most effective during the summer months of each hemisphere?

Comment: I can't tag this geoengineering because I don't have 1k rep.  Anyone who does, feel free to do so.

Comment: This idea has been thought of many times.  Check out this article   https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/environment/a13635452/scientists-earths-volcanoes-might-not-be-a-good-idea/

Comment: The Pop. Mechanics article's about making changes in the atmosphere, but the rings of Saturn are well outside its atmosphere.  (Otherwise, the particles comprising them would've "long since" been dragged deeply into it.)

Comment: The Pop Mechanics article seems like clickbait.  The linked article in nature actually seems to support the idea that reducing sunlight would be an effective counter to some climate change effects, but includes language stressing the perils of unilateral action vs international cooperation.

Comment: I have voted to close because the question belongs to https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ . Unfortunately there is no choice for this site in the "close" choices.